# Maximum sum of the number of saturdays and sundays in a leap year

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Question is to find maximum sum of the number of Saturdays and Sundays in a leap year...

I do not have much to show  off but I guess in a leap year there would be maximum of $53$ Saturdays/$53$ Sundays but i am not sure if it is possible to have $53$ Saturday and $53$ Saturdays..

So, I guess maximum sum would be $105$.

Could some one tell me if this is correct

I would like to learn something more of this kind and i would be so thankful if some one wants to say something more than this.

Comment: yes yes... This time also i won't clear...

Comment: me too, when they will put my answer sheet into the omr machine the machine will get hanged :D .. the worst part was darkening by pen :-o ..for that I am gonna miss many marks in B grp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a leap year, there can be 53 of each.  Imagine the year starts on a Saturday.  if there were only 52 Sundays, then that would mean that there are 365 days (53 Saturdays, 52 of everything else).

1972 is an example of such a year.

Comment: It makes a lot of  sense to me.... Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

A regular year has exactly $52$ full weeks, and $1$ day. A leap year has $52$ full weeks, and $2$ days. Were such a year to start on a Saturday, then it would have exactly $53$ full weekends.

Comment: simple, elegant... :) +1

Answer (score 0):

If the leap year started on a Saturday then there would be 53 Saturdays and 53 Sundays in that year. I say this because this year the year starts on a Friday and there are 53 Saturdays, but only 52 Sundays.  Whatever days are the 2 extra are the ones that will occur 53 times. In a non-leap year whichever day is the last and first will occur 53 times.

Answer (score -1):

answer is $106$ ($52\times7=364$, $2$ days would be sat and sun)
i.e. $52+52+2=106$

Comment: It seems the OP is looking for a way to find solutions, not for an answer.